# Increasing the global width of a Jekyll theme

Tags: css, jekyll

is there a way to increase the global width of a Jekyll theme? I am currently experiencing a problem when viewed on an iPhone 6 that will misalign the privacy icon in Disqus when viewed like so:

[image]

I guess this is because the width of the theme needs to be a little wider. Is there a way to fix this? Any advice on how to fix this would be greatly appreciated! thanks!

Comment: From a very quick look, removing the horizontal padding from `.content-container` might be what you're after.

Comment: @DBS brilliant! That fixed it. I just decreased the horizontal padding from `1.5rem` to `1rem`. If you want to post the answer I'll accept it. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The theme uses the class `.content-container` to manage to padding around the entire page.

The initial value for screens smaller than `38rem` (as there's a media query for larger screens) is `padding: 2rem 1rem;` Reducing the horizontal padding in this style should give you more space and prevent the image being pushed to a new line.